# Play shutdown sound in 16.04

Tags: sound, shutdown

I've read numerous threads about this particular topic. This appears to work in most of the time:

in the script named shutdownsound.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/ogg123 /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-logout.oga
```

I made all the linking:
when shutdown:
`sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/shutdownsound.sh /etc/rc0.d/K99shutdownsound.sh`

and for reboot:
`sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/shutdownsound.sh /etc/rc6.d/K99shutdownsound.sh`

I'm trying to play the oga file before the machine shuts down but I get nothing. Strangely, start-up sound does work after using similar steps.

scripts are set to be executable.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Change your prefix to "K01" like `K01shutdownsound.sh` the filesystems get unmounted at "K08"

Comment: Done. Didn't work. I'm not even getting any errors. Simply nothing.

Comment: I've got it K01 but can't hear a thing. It doesn't play. I'll try do the linking once again just to be safe.

Comment: I don't know what "ogg123" is. another script? try this and improvise on this - `/usr/bin/paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/phone-incoming-call.ogg` you can run it from the command line as you make changes to try things out

Comment: ogg123 is rather old but still very working package for playing ogg / oga files via command line. I think I've tried paplay before but I might be wrong. Will give it a whirl.

Comment: @stumblebee  I tried paplay but no change. I just don't understand why the solution works for so many people but I'm an exception.  At least an error if I'd get, just to get a hint what's wrong.

Comment: If your script works on the command line it will work when linked to `/etc/rc6.d/K01shutdownsound.sh` did you make the script executable? `chmod +x /etc/init.d/shutdownsound.sh`

Comment: Yeah when I run the command in cmd the sound kicks off just fine. That's why it's so puzzling. Scripts are set to be executable.